# Don't know why but whenever about to flag posts it shows you have flagged this post as low quality

Tags: bug, status-completed, flagging

What is happened is that whenever I am opening any new question which is not appropriate for the site it showing that I have already raised a low quality flag post for this question but I haven't. Why is it showing then that I have raised a low quality flag. Although I am still able to flag the post as not suitable for the site but I would like to know why it is showing I have raised a quality flag before for every new non suitable for this site question I am about to flag.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I could swear this was asked and answered here yesterday but I can't find the question at all!  This: [I did not flag all these posts as Very Low Quality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364136/i-did-not-flag-all-these-posts-as-very-low-quality) is the relevant post on MSE.

UPDATE: as of the time of this update the post there now has an answer saying that the bug is fixed.  (Amplitwist also notes in the comments that the status-complete tag has been assigned to it too).